# Excel: Separate Currency Values from Rest of Line

Tags: worksheet-function, data-validation, microsoft-office-2016, finance, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following conundrum, which I think will be helpful for a lot of people.  I have been pulling down data from bank statements (yes, I could use Mint; no, I don't want to for various reasons), and I have ended up with results such as the following (slight redaction for privacy, # in place of numbers):

SUNOCO ########## SOMEPLACE CA #### ##### 23.16

The column used to have two dates in front of the transaction, but I used Text-To-Columns to break them out.  The problem now, however, is that I need to break out the dollar value (23.16) out of the rest of the line, but cannot use fixed width (the values are longer or shorter) and cannot delimit by a character (because I would have to manually insert something like a semi-colon into every single line).

Perhaps a find/replace?  There are no other decimals in the lines except for the money values, so optimally, that would replace anything conforming to a mask with a semicolon + the value (e.g. 1,231 would become ; 1,231) and then I could use Text-To-Columns to separate based on the semicolon.  But I am not sure how to do that.

Thoughts?  I really don't want to break all values out manually.

Comment: Look for the last space character.  The currency value starts in the next position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Excel 2016 you have several options.

1. Flash Fill - Type the first number into the next empty column. Start typing the second number and see how Flash Fill suggests the rest. Accept the suggestion with the Enter key.

[image]

2. Get and transform - Make the data into a table (Insert > Table), then click Data > Get & Transform > From Table.  Click the column with the data, then the Transform ribbon > Split columns > by delimiter > select the space and tick "At the right-most delimiter". Hit OK and rename the columns, then save the query and load it to the workbook.

[image]

You can now add more data to your original data table and refresh the query to perform the same operation again.

Comment: I used the second method, as it seems the more powerful.  It works very well, and saved me a lot of time!  Thanks!